# Python's inspect.Signature's signature seems to violate python's signatures rules

Tags: python, python-internals

How did the inspect module make it **seem** like an argument doesn't have a default (though it does), and what would be the reason for doing this (if at all any)?

The help of inspect.Signature shows `return_annotation` argument without a default:

```py
>>> import inspect
>>> help(inspect.Signature)
(...)
class Signature(builtins.object)
 |  Signature(parameters=None, *, return_annotation, __validate_parameters__=True)
(...)
```

Yet one can construct a Signature with only one argument:

```py
>>> sig = inspect.Signature(None)
>>> # Nothing bad happens
```

This seems to violate the rules. So looking at the code for the `Signature` class, I see:

```py
def __init__(self, parameters=None, *, return_annotation=_empty, __validate_parameters__=True)
```

Alright, `return_annotation` does have a default after all (which is why `inspect.Signature(None)` works).

So the questions are:

How did the inspect module achieve this trickery?
Is there a **good** rational for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `help` calls `inspect.signature(object)` under the hood, where `object` is the function. This treats the `inspect.Signature.empty` default argument in such a way that it's *shown* as having no default value at all.

Another example:

```
>>> def thing(self, a=inspect.Signature.empty):
...     ...
... 
>>> help(thing)
Help on function thing in module __main__:

thing(self, a)  # Here it is!
```

You can see what the `help` function does under the hood by running this:

```
import trace
trace.Trace().runfunc(help, thing)
```

For me (Python 3.6) it shows this:

```
<snip>
pydoc.py(1357):             try:
pydoc.py(1358):                 signature = inspect.signature(object)
 --- modulename: inspect, funcname: signature
inspect.py(3002):     return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
 --- modulename: inspect, funcname: from_callable
inspect.py(2751):         return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
<snip>
pydoc.py(1361):             if signature:
pydoc.py(1362):                 argspec = str(signature)
```

If you replicate this in your code, you'll get this:

```
>>> inspect.signature(thing)
<Signature (self, a)>
>>> str(_)
'(self, a)'  # huh?!
```

Comment: Thanks @ForceBru. I got as far as seeing it had to do with `inspect._empty` (which `inspect.Signature.empty` points to, but can't see **how** the `_empty` type would declare itself as "invisible" in the help, or **why** it would do so.

Comment: It just marks the argument as having no default value. If you were to implement `inspect.Signature` in a different way, you could've chosen a different representation of such arguments, so that's not really "trickery", that's more of an implementation detail.